# Android - imagegetter java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: android

I have html text and I'm parsing it into TextView. The text has image so I found `imagegetter`.

The code of `imagegetter`:

```
 spanned = Html.fromHtml(content, new Html.ImageGetter() {

            @Override
            public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {

                /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), source,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

                Drawable drawable = null;
                if (source.startsWith("http")) {
                    // load from internet

                    URL sourceURL;
                    try {
                        sourceURL = new URL(source);
                        URLConnection urlConnection = sourceURL.openConnection();
                        urlConnection.connect();
                        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream =
                                new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
                        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);

                        // convert Bitmap to Drawable
                        drawable = new BitmapDrawable(resources, bm);

                        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
                        Point size = new Point();
                        display.getSize(size);
                        int width = size.x;
                        int height = size.y;

                        int k = width / bm.getWidth();

                        if(k > 2) { k = 2; }

                        drawable.setBounds(0, 0,
                                bm.getWidth() * k,
                                bm.getHeight() * k);

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {
                    // load from local drawable
                }

                return drawable;
            }

        }, null);
```

It works fine, but when it has URL:

> [http://www.svetandroida.cz/media/2016/06/android-pro-začátečníky-velikost-SIM.jpg](http://www.svetandroida.cz/media/2016/06/android-pro-za%C4%8D%C3%A1te%C4%8Dn%C3%ADky-velikost-SIM.jpg)

It gets

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   [http://www.svetandroida.cz/media/2016/06/android-pro-začátečníky-velikost-SIM.jpg](http://www.svetandroida.cz/media/2016/06/android-pro-za%C4%8D%C3%A1te%C4%8Dn%C3%ADky-velikost-SIM.jpg)

How can I solve it ?

Comment: What line is the logcat error on?

Comment: InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileNotFoundException` is returned when the server returns an error indicating the page does not exist.  Although, in your case the page does exist, I think you're getting the error because of the accented characters in your url - i.e. `č`, `á` and `í`.

You need to URL encode the characters so that your URL becomes:

```
http://www.svetandroida.cz/media/2016/06/android-pro-za%C4%8D%C3%A1te%C4%8Dn%C3%ADky-velikost-SIM.jpg
```